# É possível carregar classes dinamicamente e usá-las como tipo?

Tags: java, compilação, instanciar-objeto

Estou tentando fazer um código que carregue classes dinamicamente e possa usá-las para criar instancias e serem usadas para cast. Eu consigo criar uma instância na classe recém carregada usando o método `minhaclasse.newInstance()` , mas não consigo usar a classe recém carregada como se fosse um tipo. Por exemplo: `minhaClasse meuObj = new minhaClasse();` Não funciona. É possível fazer isso?

Segue o código que eu estava tentando fazer:

```
URL classUrl;
classUrl = new URL("file:///C:/classes/");
URL[] classUrls = { classUrl };
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(classUrls);
Class c = ucl.loadClass("Operation");
Class MyIn = ucl.loadClass("MyInter"); 
Object o = c.newInstance(); //ISSO FUNCIONA
System.out.println(((MyIn) o).sum(2, 4)); //ISSO NÃO FUNCIONA. Mensagem de erro: MyIn cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: Seria possivel utilizar `MyIn.cast(o)` mas mesmo assim, vc não teria a garantia de quais métodos é composto a classe do objeto `MyIn`. Talvez para executar esse método, seria possivel usar reflexão, se você souber os nomes dos métodos ou os tiver em algum xml, por exemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível.

Java é uma linguagem de tipos fortes. Isso significa que o compilador verifica se os métodos e atributos que você está acessando existem e são compatíveis com o uso do código. A única forma de se fazer isso é se o compilador tem acesso às classes que estão sendo usadas e o código está importando corretamente essas dependências.

Se fosse possível usar tipagem fraca como em linguagens de script o cast não teria vantagem alguma, bastaria chamar um método qualquer no objeto genérico e pronto.

Enfim, o que você está tentando fazer é basicamente forçar o Java a criar um tipo dinamicamente sem no entanto apresentar uma definição desse tipo.

Para acessar métodos e atributos de classes carregadas dinamicamente, você deve usar reflexão. Já existem algumas respostas aqui, inclusive minhas que ensinam a fazer isto, mas basicamente você pode usar o método `getMethod` da classe e recuperar uma referência ao método, depois você usa o método `invoke` para executar o método.

Veja um exemplo extraído da [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html):

```
public class InvokeMain {
    public static void main(String... args) {   
        try {    
            Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]);     
            Class[] argTypes = new Class[] { String[].class };   
            Method main = c.getDeclaredMethod("main", argTypes);     
            String[] mainArgs = Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, args.length);    
            System.out.format("invoking %s.main()%n", c.getName());      
            main.invoke(null, (Object)mainArgs);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {     
            x.printStackTrace(); 
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException x) {      
            x.printStackTrace();    
        } catch (IllegalAccessException x) {     
            x.printStackTrace();    
        } catch (InvocationTargetException x) {      
            x.printStackTrace();    
        } 
    } 
}
```